# Arguments in if statements are ignored 1/2 the time

Tags: robotframework

```
*** variables ***
${x}    0
*** Test Cases ***
Test1
    run keyword if   ${x} == 1    run keywords
    ...    print    hi
    ...    ELSE
    ...    print    hi
Test2
    run keyword if   ${x} == 0    run keywords
    ...    print    hi
    ...    ELSE
    ...    print    hi    
*** keywords ***
print
   [arguments]   ${x}
   log to console     ${x}
```

Output:

```
Test1                                                                 hi
Test1                                                                 | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test2                                                                 | FAIL |
Keyword 'print' expected 1 argument, got 0.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What is going on here? Arguments at the second print work but are ignored at the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that in one case you're calling `run keywords` (with arguments) and in the other case you're running `print` (with arguments).

We can reformat your code to show how robot is looking at it:

```
run keyword if   ${x} == 1
...    run keywords    print  hi
...    ELSE
...    print    hi
```

When the expression is false, you fall through and run `print  hi`, and everything works.

When the case is true, robot runs `run keywords   print  hi`. `run keywords` treats each of its arguments as a separate keyword to run so it tries to run `print`, and then it tries to run `hi`. Since you aren't giving an argument to print, it throws the error.

Comment: Ahhhh, that makes sense. I was using "run keywords" trying to solve other problems earlier, I guess keeping it caused more. Thanks! This all started with me trying to send args and return a value from a keyword, all inside an if statement. I ended up just using suite variables and eliminating all the args and returns, is there a more kosher way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

The issue comes from you expecting the `hi` to be passed as an argument to `print` in the `run keywords` construct, but robot doesn't treat it that way, the `hi` is just another keyword to be ran.

In [`Run Keywords` documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keywords) there's a paragraph how to use keywords with arguments in it - you have to chain the keywords with an `AND`:

> ... keywords can also be run with arguments using upper case AND as a separator between keywords. The keywords are executed so that the first argument is the first keyword and proceeding arguments until the first AND are arguments to it. First argument after the first AND is the second keyword and proceeding arguments until the next AND are its arguments. And so on.

In your case:

```
run keyword if   ${x} == 1    run keywords
...    print    hi    AND     No Operation
...    ELSE
...    print    hi
```

, will now change the call to "run the keyword `print` with an argument 'hi', and then run the keyword `No Operation`" (which does literally nothing, comes in handy for situations like this).